# Kendo Grid Filtering on integer column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a grid with multiple columns.
say `Id(integer)`,`Name(string)` etc.
Change event is working fine for name column.But for ID column it is not working(change event is not firing for numeric column in kendo).

I have done in client side scripting. But I want this functionality to be in server side(Razor).

I am new to Kendo UI and any help on how to do this would be much appreciated.

I am attaching my code below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("ViewDataGrid")

                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ID").Width(150);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(" Name").Width(150);

                            })
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto; width: 2200px" })
                            .Filterable(i => i.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))

                            .Sortable(s => s.AllowUnsort(false).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                            .Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true))                               
                            .Pageable(r => r.PreviousNext(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(20)
                            .ServerOperation(false)
                            .Events(e => e.Change("call"))


))


function call(e) {

        debugger;

                var filterlength = e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters.length;
                var ds = $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                $filter = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < filterlength; i++) {
                    if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[i].field == "Id")
                        $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "eq", value: parseInt(e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value) });
                    else
                        $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "contains", value: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value });
                }

                $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter = $filter;
                $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sync();         



        }
```

Model.CS

```
   public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<GridData> dataList = new List<GridData>(); 
    GridData data1 = new GridData();
        data1.Id = 9191919;
        data1.Name = "XYZ";           
        dataList.Add(data1);
        return View(dataList);           
    }
```

After Editing:
Change Event is not firing.
Could you please help me to resolve my issue.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("ViewDataGrid")
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
{
toolBar.Template(
    @<Text>
    <input type="search" id="searchBox" class="SearchRight SearchTopMargin" />
    <b class="FloatRight SearchTopMarginExtra">Search the grid: </b>
    </Text>);
})
```

.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto; width: 2200px" })
                                .Filterable(i => i.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))

```
                            .Sortable(s => s.AllowUnsort(false).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                            .Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true))
                            .Events(e => e.Change("call"))
                            .Pageable(r => r.PreviousNext(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Custom()
    .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerPaging(false)
    .ServerSorting(false)
    .ServerFiltering(false)
    .Transport(transport => transport
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Index"))
    )
    .Schema(schema => schema
        .Data("Data")
        .Total("Total")
        .Errors("Errors")
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id("Id");
            model.Field("Id", typeof(int));
            model.Field("Name", typeof(string));

        })

    )
)
```

)

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: And how is your dataSource setup/configured?

Comment: We are just passing the static data from the controller.Please find controller code also.

Comment: Okay this might be a long shot but this ended up doing it for me, instead of passing the dataSource directly I ended up also specifying the "schema" in the dataSource's configuration. I followed telerik's custom dataSource API reference: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/custom-datasource. Hope it helps

Comment: If I did like this Kendo Grid change event is not firing . Please help me.

Comment: Actually, my requirement is Whenever the user entering input in filters, the Kendo grid should display the matching records based on input.For this, I have written a change event on kendo grid. This is working fine for strings. But for integer columns change event is not working.

Comment: Will get back to you as soon as I can on this, just need to wrap up a few stuff on my side. I may have a solution to this.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I might have a solution, please let me know if this works for you:

**RAZOR**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("ViewDataGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ID").Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(" Name").Width(150);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .Filterable(i => i.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))
    .Sortable(s => s.AllowUnsort(false).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true))                               
    .Pageable(r => r.PreviousNext(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("call")) // try to bound the event
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerPaging(false)
            .ServerSorting(false)
            .ServerFiltering(false)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Index"))
    )
)
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    function call(e) {

        //debugger;
        //console.log(e) //Log e and look through the object data.

        var filterlength = e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters.length;
        var ds = $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        $filter = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < filterlength; i++) {
            if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[i].field == "Id")
                $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "eq", value: parseInt(e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value) });
            else
                $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "contains", value: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value });
        }

        $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter = $filter;
        $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sync();         
    }
</script>
```

If this doesn't work then there might be work some sort of work around. Maybe trying with your initial implementation: Try to parse or use the ID column "c.Id" as string and handle it the same way as the Name field "c.Name", something like:

```
e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value.toString()
```

This might not be the best work around but if you have already tried this I am sure there must be another way.  You might find this API reference also useful:

[Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent GridBuilder aspnet-mvc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBuilder)

I will still look into this on my side try replicating the issue and if I do happen to find anything I will update my post/answer immediately.

Good luck.

Comment: Now I am facing one more issue.I have o pass filter operators dynamically. In existing functionality, it is returning results for contains operator even though I have selected 'Does not contains'. Please help me.                 $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "contains", value: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value